# Serializing a non-JSON javascript object in java

Tags: javascript, java, json, serialization

I have a java project where I am trying to serialize a javascript object that later needs to be viewed in a browser.  I'd been using `org.json.JSONObject` to generate the javascript object, and that works great for basic json-friendly types.  Recently I have a need to add javascript functions to the serialized javascript, but this `JSONObject` doesn't seem to offer a good path to serialize javascript functions.

I'd really like to end up with something like this:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": function (x, y) {
    return x+y;
  }
}
```

I'm happy to define some custom serializer in java for the function, but I've had trouble seeing how I could extend `JSONObject` to accomplish that.  I have shamefully used this workaround for now, where I create a json structure of known shape...

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": {
    "function": {
      "args": ["x", "y"],
      "body": "return x+y;"
    }
  }
}
```

...and then converting it to a real function on the browser client side.  This seems to work, but I'd really prefer just more cleanly serializing the function in the first place.

From java, how can I serialize a javascript object that contains javascript functions?

Comment: Does Java recognize Javascript functions as functions?  Or are they strings in Java?

Comment: I imagined I'd have to create some simple custom java class to correctly serialize it, but JSONObject doesn't seem too friendly in allowing types to expose their own serializers.  All my functions happen to be really short text, but it just seems goofy to have to re-configure it all on the client like I'm doing.  Anyway, my internal representation for these in java right now is just simple constant strings.

Comment: It depends on how you plan to feed this data into Javascript.  If you have to send it as a response to an AJAX request, it's not going to be as easy.  If you're writing it to a JSP (or similar server script) page, you can just output the object string with functions and it will be parsed as javascript by the browser.

Comment: I'm basically just writing a js file to be loaded directly by the browser via a `<script>` tag, and this object is one part of that file.

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to get JSONObject to produce exactly the right JS with methods.  Something hacky like assign a special ID instead of the method, let JSONObject produce a JSON string, and then a search and replace (for the ID, replacing it with proper function code).